# TYPO3 TCA inline with wizard

Tags: typo3, typo3-9.x

[image]

In TYPO3 9.5 LTS, Is there a TCA option to change the inline new relation btn (1) to something like the form suggest (2) so that a popup does not appear?

Actually, clicking on button (1) opens a popup to select the product to add. I need to avoid this popup with a solution like the one of input field (2) where editor can type some letters and a list of records containing those letters appear. Is not mandatory that the selection is same as (2), even a select field populated with the products could do the job. The important thing is that it doesn't open a popup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved changing the TCA type of the column `uid_local` that references to the product records from type `group` to type `select` and adding the parameter `foreign_table` with the name of the products table.

This is the result:
[image]

Now, to select a product, the editor just have to choose one from the list. No more popup.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure what you want to archive. I'd suggest you install the [typo3/cms-styleguide](https://packagist.org/packages/typo3/cms-styleguide#9.2.4) package (version ^9.2 should be suitable for TYPO3 9.5).

In the TCA section you can see examples of all possibilities you have with TCA.

Comment: I updated my question to make what I want to achieve more clear.

Comment: Please post a code snippet of your TCA. I'm still not sure what you mean. Is it a behaviour similar to EXT:powermail, where you have form, that has pages which consist of form fields? That's TCA `'type' => 'inline'`.

Comment: Thanks for trying to help, but I don't know how to explain it better than this and posting my TCA won't help because there's nothing wrong in it, I just want to make it working on another way. I want to select records with `inline` type fields (IRRE) *without opening a popup*, like `group` type does with its search field.

Comment: I add that it's not necessary that the field is of `inline` type but I think that I have no other type to use since the relation has an additional field `quantity` as you can see from the screenshot.